# QTextToSpeech Set Default QLocale

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, locale, text-to-speech

In Qt 5.9.0, The [QTextToSpeech](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtspeech-index.html) class provides a convenient access to text-to-speech engines.

There is a Qt example for QTextToSpeech [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtspeech-hello-speak-example.html).

How Can I change locale and write other language(non-english) ?

I tried this code, not working:

```
QLocale locale;
locale.setDefault(QLocale::Persian);
m_speech->setLocale(locale);
```

[image: Example Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

You need to first validate if the locale you are looking for is available on your platform with [`QTextToSpeech::availableLocales()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexttospeech.html#availableLocales) public function and then you may use if that is available.